# supremum and convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, convolution

Let $f, g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be nice functions (so everything below make sense ) and let $g_t(x)=g(x/t)$ for $t>0.$

Can we say that $$\sup_{t>0} (g_t\ast f)(x)= \left(\sup_{t>0} g_t \right) \ast f (x)$$?
(Here, $\ast$  is the standard [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)) If not, what we can  expect?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your notation, $\sup_{t>0} g_t$ is simply a step function? It is equal to $\sup_{x<0} g(x)$ for $x<0$, $g(0)$ for $x=0$, and $\sup_{x>0} g(x)$ for $x>0$? Because $g_t(x)$ "goes through" all of the $g-$values with the same sign as $x$, as $t$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$.